# How to compute the derivative of a curve?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, computational-mathematics

Sorry for the naivety of the question, my field is not mathematics. I am writing a script to calculate the derivative of a curve given by a set of `(x,y)` points as

```
(x,y)
1,3
2,2
3,7
4,7
5,8
6,12
```

I calculate the `dy/dx` for each point from the slope over a unit of `x` as `y(n+1)-y(n)` to produce

```
(x,dy/dx)
2,-1
3,5
4,0
5,1
6,4
```

Is it mathematically correct? Do I calculate `dy/dx` correctly?

The given curve is not a mathematical function but an empirical set of data (say x=time, y=temperature). Is it the correct way to calculate the `dy/dx` for the available set of data?

**EDIT:** Probably, it is meaningless to calculate the slope between two given points. Instead, it is better to draw a curve based on the best fit. Then, we will have a better approximation of the data points where the slope at each point is meaningful.

Am I right? Should I recalculate the `y` values based on a best-fit approximation before trying to calculate the slope?

Comment: There are infinitely many curves that pass through your given points $(x,y)$, with wildly varying slopes, so this information is not enough to "determine" $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Perhaps you should explain what you mean to accomplish by calculating the derivative.

Comment: Include *any* information you have about the function $y$. What does it represent, what properties does it have?

Comment: This is just a typical set of data, and the script aims to calculate dy/dx for empirical data given to the script. Is there any other way to calculate the derivative for a given set of data?

Comment: Are you looking for the [discrete derivative](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Discrete_derivative)?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302160/correct-way-to-calculate-numeric-derivative-in-discrete-time) and numerical differentiation.

Comment: @user121330 I believe so. Is discrete derivative a simplified form of standard derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to fit a cubic spline through the data, and then calculate the derivative.

See [scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html)

Then use the `.Derivative()` method to get what you want.

Comment: Great suggestion. I was looking at SciPy for curve fitting.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that the underlying function $y$ is several times differentiable for all $x$ in an interval which covers your range of values. This is a reasonable assumption, as temperatures rarely vary abruptly and certainly not on a microscopic scale.

If this assumption is satisfied, then you can certainly approximate the derivative of $y$ at each of your points using finite difference approximations. It simplify matters that the data points are equidistant on the $x$ axis. Let $h$ denote their constant separation. In your case $h=1$.

If $x$ is an internal point, i.e., both $x-h$ and $x+h$ are data points, then the standard space central approximation of $y'(x)$ is
$$ y'(x) \approx \frac{y(x+h) - y(x-h)}{2h} $$
The absolute value of the error is $O(h^2)$, i.e. it is bounded by a constant times $h^2$.

If $x$ is an endpoint, say the left end point, then you can either use
$$ y'(x) \approx \frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h},$$
where the error is $O(h)$ or a one side approximation, such as
$$ y'(x) \approx \frac{-3 y(x) + 4y(x+h) - y(x+2h)}{2h},$$
where the error is $O(h^2)$.

More elaborate approximations are possible and precise error estimates can also be derived, but we either need more information about the properties of $y$ or more data points so that information can be inferred from the data.

Comment: I edited the question. I believe that my problem is that the raw data points are not reliable and should be polished before calculating the derivative.

Comment: @All You are quite right. Divided differences are very vulnerable to errors in the input. Fitting a curve to your data may very well be your best option. However, which class of curve to use is very problem dependent. Relevant keywords are: numerical differentiation with noisy data/perturbed data.

Comment: I remember reading that at the molecular level temperature is quantized.